# Get information (GCM Token) from Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

This might be a very short and trivial question, but how do I get information from Xamarin.Android to Xamarin.Forms?

Basically, what I would like to do is the following:

- First I retrieve a token in my Android project from the Google Play
  Services.
- Then I start my main application and show a login screen.
- During the login I would like to forward the token to my server, so he is aware of my token and can send me messages.

Is that a good idea? How do I get my token into the Forms part of my application?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options for communicating between Xamarin.Forms and the individual platform specific projects.

You can call into Xamarin.Forms from each project rather easily by accessing the Xamarin.Forms.Application class and it's "Current" property which will give you the instance of your Xamarin.Forms application.

You can also do the reverse - call into your specific platform project by utilising the DependencyService class from your shared Xamarin.Forms code. With async/await and TaskCompletionSource this can be a good way to abstract the inherent async nature of obtaining tokens on android/ios into a single awaitable function call.
You can find more information on DependencyService [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/)

Lastly, from what I gather, you are figuring out how to register for push notifications. It might be best to simply use the PushNotifications plugin located [here](https://github.com/rdelrosario/xamarin-plugins/tree/master/PushNotification).

It should help you get started. Be sure to read through the documentation. There are a bunch of steps needed to get everything working.

If you have more specific questions or get stuck somewhere, post a new question, I have integrated push notifications on both Android and iOS succesfully before and might be able to help you out.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Unfortunately I saw that the PushNotificationService needs android 5.0+, is that true? Also, I am not sure, what is that library doing for me?

Comment: My app is using push notifications and I regularly test it on 4.2, 5.0 and 6.0. When dealing with local notifications, there are things you can only do on 5.0 and up, but push notifications most certainly do work. That library is meant to handle registration and unregistering for you, as well as parse incoming messages and create local notifications. I have personally not used it, as I'm using azure notification hub, but it can still be a good source to checkout how some of the features are implemented.

Comment: So, what does it "Must compile against 21 as plugin is using API 21 specific things. [...]" mean then in their documentation? It has to compile to 21, but works with earlier Levels, as long as I don't use the features requiring level 21? And what do you mean with registration? Do you mean, it does the registration at Google and return of the token etc for me and also receives all Messages? So I won't need to register GCM myself?

Comment: That is right. You should *in general* always compile against the latest API version, and you only use the newer features where supported. Yes, this plugin handles contacting the GCM for you, as well as implementing the service and the listener needed to receive messages. it also has it's vision of how you can format push notifications (which is something that is up to app developers to define) and it parses the messages according to that vision. You should probably explore the repo and learn from it. You don't have to actually use it if you want to design something more specific for your use.

Comment: OK, I think this will help me, I will try it out later today, when I'm back home. Will give you some feedback. BTW: What happens, if I use a feature of that plugin which needs 21, but I run it on < 21, will it crash, does it even install correctly?

Comment: If you try and use it, it will crash. You will see in the plugin that features that are specific to newer versions are surrounded by if checks, checking the version number before calling the newer api functionalities. If done properly, everything runs fine, you just, of course, don't get to use the new stuff on old os versions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109599/discussion-between-jannik-and-irreal).